# GoLang : Passing buildFlags with double quotes in launch.json of visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I would like to pass something with quotes as buildFlags in My launch.json.
currently this is what I am trying to do

```
"buildFlags": "-ldflags \"-w -X xxxxxxx\"",
```

However using the escape character gives me the error

```
invalid value "\"-w" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details. (exit status 2)
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Use single quotes: `"buildFlags": "-ldflags '-s -w'"`

Answer (score 0):

Per this issue [launch.json buildFlags for multiple tags](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1901), the following config should work

```
"buildFlags": "-ldflags '-w -X'"
```

For more information, please refer to this doc [VS Code debugging](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)